# I want to design a spacer pcb with no copper on either side

Tags: eaglecad

I want to design a 2.5" x 0.7" spacer pcb in the free version of Eagle, with no copper or components on either side with four (unplated) 0.116" diameter holes. Eagle won't generate a board if the schematic is empty. And Eagle CAD doesn't list a 0.116" drill in the drill size drop down window.  Any ideas on how to do the above?  Thanks!

Comment: You can type in the drill "drop down" for any size drill you want.

Answer (score 3):

In the control panel, go to `File -> New -> Board`.

Now simply place four drill holes using the `hole` tool and draw your outline on the `Dimension` layer using a `wire` with a width of `0`.

To make a hole of the desired size, simply type the size you want into the drill size box (you aren't limited to selecting values from the drop down).

---

Alternatively, once you have opened a new board, simply run the following commands:

```
grid inch 0.1 off;
Layer Dimension;
Set Wire_Bend 0;
Wire 0  (0 0) (2.5 0.7) (0 0);
hole 0.116   (0.2 0.2) (0.2 0.5) (2.3 0.2) (2.3 0.5);
grid last
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  My pcb is in production at PCBWay.